# How to apply progress bar by using AFHTTPRequestOperationManager (AFNetworking 2.0),Xcode 5,iOS7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, afnetworking-2

My code is

```
NSString *const BaseURLString = @"http://192.168.1.202:81//CredentialsModule/CredentialService.asmx/LogInUser";
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager=[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters =[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"qwerty",@"UserName",@"qwerty@123",@"Password", nil ] ;
AFJSONRequestSerializer *requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

[requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[requestSerializer setValue:@"" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];

manager.requestSerializer = requestSerializer;
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
[ manager  POST:BaseURLString parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);

NSLog(@"Content-lent: %lld", [operation.response expectedContentLength]);



} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Error: %@",  operation.response);

}];
```

How can I apply progress bar? It should be in success part.

Comment: You want to show upload progress, or just completion?

Comment: i want to show progress on each and every bytes receive from server.

Comment: You won't get notified of 'every byte', it will be each packet sent at best. Did you search for 'progress' related methods in AFNetworking code base?

Comment: Ya,I searched but it work on AfHttpRequestoperation not in AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.

Comment: So you have an idea of how to solve the problem. How can you use it? How can the manager help you?

Comment: [GET/POST/etc calls to AFHTTPRequestOperationManager return an AFHTTPRequestOperation](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/86b3bd85622bb496052ed27663509f7fe6d44dab/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h#L226-L230). So use the [returned operation and call](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/207b04fe626370f436f2171f2e6e2b9951dcd6cc/AFNetworking/AFURLConnectionOperation.h#L269) [operation setDownloadProgress].